# Why does GeoServer WMS not work in OpenLayers? Problem viewing GeoServer layers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

Adding two layers using OpenLayers, one map layer from OSM, second layer adding from GeoServer localhost. But when I load single OSM layer it's showing by default map.

It's okay, but when adding second layer it's not working. it's also disappear old layer map also
and when I remove first layer it's won't show anything from second layer

```
var MapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        var myView = new ol.View({
            center: [74.1296577, 32.2739606],
            zoom: 4,
            projection: projection
        });
        var mymap = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DHAGIS/wms',
            params: { 'LAYERS': 'DHAGIS:baddoki', 'TILED': true, 'STYLES': 'graves' },
            serverType: 'geoserver',

        });
        var mylayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source=mymap
        });
        //////////////////////////
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [MapLayer, mylayer
            ],
            view: myView
        });
```

Comment: What's in Geoserver's log (in verbose mode) after you make the GetMap request ? Can you preview the layer with Geoserver's built-in preview ?

Comment: `source=mymap` should be `source: mymap`

Comment: We need to check the console, on the browser, using the development tools. You will find the errors displayed on the console.

Comment: Mike i already changed source=mymap  like  source: mymap

Comment: and layer preview in geoserver working fine but when  i try to access inside my web application its showing nothing

Comment: Your view projection is presumably EPSG:4326 with those center coordinates, you haven't specified a projection for the mymap source so it will default to EPSG:3857 and be reprojected by the OpenLayers client.  Was that your intention?